# Converting datetime.txt to sequential names.txt in Python

Tags: python-3.x, date, time, sequence

I am a new Python user.  I have a bunch of files like this:

```
201201110000.txt
201201110030.txt
201201110100.txt
.....
```

and now I want to change these files into:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
......
```

Could you offer some help?

Comment: How do you propose to map the old names to the new names?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I just want to make it easier for looping in Python. Is there another way to read it directly without renaming the old files.

Comment: Yes there are ways to loop over files in python.  But if that is what you need , that is what you should ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` that can call a `shell command` like below, for this purpose

```
import subprocess
cmd = '''ls *.txt | sort | awk 'BEGIN{ a=1 }{ printf "mv %s test%0d.txt\\n", $0, a++ }' | bash'''
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

**PS**: If you want to make copies of files, instead of `mv` use `cp`

Comment: @Barack please check it